Tkinter Button no longer works once in Fullscreen
Previously I had thought it was a module import issue, as in the difference between the base tkinter and tkinter.ttk widgets, but it was a fullscreen issue and I don't know why. Basically, I wrote the most simple way to replicate this issue, by creating a button with a bound command to print 1 if clicked.
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk() 

b = Button(root, text="test", command=lambda: print(1)) 
b.pack()

root.mainloop()

The above code works perfectly fine if not in fullscreen and it prints 1 once clicked, however the moment you go into fullscreen it required me to click, hold, and drag the cursor slightly for the button to register a click. Any ideas?
Oh, and I am using a macOS, which I suspect may be the issue, running python 3.9.12, and tkinter 8.6.
I got the versions from running
python --version

in terminal, and
import tkinter 
tkinter.TkVersion

in the python shell
